# update class variable using function defined within self

Tags: python

I have something like this:

```
class updateMyNumber:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = update_number(number)

    def update_number(self, number):
        self.number = number * 2

inst = updateMyNumber(5)
```

I get the following error:

> NameErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>   ----> 1 inst = updateMyNumber(5)
>
> in **init**(self, number)
>         1 class updateMyNumber:
>         2     def **init**(self, number):
>   ----> 3         self.number = update_number(number)
>         4 
>         5     def update_number(self, number):
>
> NameError: name 'update_number' is not defined

I want the `inst` to return `25`. What's the best way to define the class?

**Note: I don't want to write self.number = number * 2**

Comment: "Note: I don't want to write self.number = number * 2" Then use another language. The explicit `self` is here to stay in Python. I suppose you could refactor all your code to use closures and nested scopes [for simulating classes](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578091-simple-tool-for-simulating-classes-using-closures-/), if you really wanted to. I would suggest just using the language constructs as they were intended, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you should call the `self` method:

```
class updateMyNumber:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.update_number(number)

    def update_number(self, number):
        self.number = number * 2
```

but better way to setting instance variables **inside `__init__`**, read the [should-all-member-variables-be-initialized-in-init](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20661448/python-should-all-member-variables-be-initialized-in-init)

so i recomend you, something:

```
class updateMyNumber:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = self.update_number(number)

    def update_number(self, number):
        return number * 2
```